# iOS Photo app doesn't show created album (more than 800 pictures)

Tags: ios, photos, alassetslibrary, alassetsgroup

I've created function to create new album and add pictures from camera roll (by using ALAssetsLibrary and AlAssetsGroup). When I'm trying to add more than 800 pictures, my new album is not showing in iOS Photos app. I have to kill it and open it again to reload all albums. 
Interesting thing is open UIImagePickerController just after finish, showing new created album which is impossible using Photos app.

Is there any posibility to notify iOS Photo app to reload data? Could be a bug of system app?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to register an observer for `ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification` where it is sent when the contents of the assets library have changed from under the app that is using the data.